# retrive data from android sqlite using user input

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a small database app.   It requires a user to enter a code 1A1 for example to search the Db.

If I hard code the sql command it will find that row.

```
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from emdcode WHERE code = '1A1'",null);
```

On my layout I have a text box for user input

```
        <EditText
    android:id="@+id/codelookup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:ems="10" >
    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

My question>  How do I write the SQL to search for the user input?

I have done this in Java

```
     private void SrchCodeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
```

{

```
String sql =  "SELECT * FROM emdcodes WHERE Codes like ?";

        try 
{
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);    
    ps.setString(1, EMDCODELOOKUP.getText() + "%");        
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    ResultsTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));      
    } 

catch (Exception e) 
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
      }
```

So I assumned SQLite is similar

I have tried

```
      Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from emdcode WHERE code = codelookup",null);

      Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from emdcode WHERE code = ?",null);
```

Any Suggestions or guidemnce would be great.    Thank you

update

When using Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from emdcode WHERE code = ?", new String[]{"codelookup"}); 
I get a null result set.  This is the logcat file:

```
    07-31 00:10:34.735: E/Trace(1765): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     ... 11 more
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.example.studentdatabase.MainActivity.showdata(MainActivity.java:47)
07-31 00:10:38.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     ... 14 more
07-31 00:11:55.095: E/Trace(1839): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-31 00:20:08.084: E/Trace(2020): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     ... 11 more
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at com.example.studentdatabase.MainActivity.showdata(MainActivity.java:47)
07-31 00:20:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     ... 14 more
07-31 00:32:07.675: E/Trace(2296): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-31 00:33:22.405: E/Trace(2377): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public Cursor GetData(String Code) throws Exception 
    {   
        Cursor cursor;

        cursor = this.db.query("emdcode",null, "code = "+Code, null, null, null, null,null );

        return cursor;
    }
```

or

```
public Cursor GetData(String Code) throws Exception 
    {   
        Cursor cursor;

        cursor = this.db.query("emdcode",null, "code = ?", new String[]{code}, null, null, null,null );

        return cursor;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try.

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from emdcode WHERE code = ?", new String[]{theStringYouWantToSearchForHere});
```

You almost had it when you used the ?. The 2nd argument should be a string array for the where arguments.

If you look at the logcat,

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
```

Means that the string you are parsing into the array is null, resulting in the crash

If you put

```
String search = "1A1";
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from emdcode WHERE code = ?", new String[]{search});
```

That should work.

It means you are not initialising your search value before you call this method (most likely).

Edit: For the Edit text

You want to get the edit text value.
Something like

```
EditText codelookup = (EditText) ActivityName.this.findViewById(R.id.codelookup);
String search = codelookup.getText().toString();
```

Note that here I assume you are inside of the activity for findViewById. If you are going to use this alot I suggest you have the editTextFor codelookup as a class variable. Where you would only have to find it once (note that you would need to have the findViewById after the setContentView()).

Comment: Maybe I am not quite understanding were the String is coming from.

Comment: Maybe I am not quite understanding were the String is coming from. I have tried ?", new String[]{'"+codelookup+"'});   I have tried ="@+id/codelookup.  I keep getting a error - unfortanly, Code lookup app has stopped.      any suggestions??

Comment: Are you able to post the logcat that you get when it crashes?

Comment: Can you please also add the whole enitre method for the call. I'm assumming the string is null.

Comment: I tried but it is too long by about 3000 charactors.   How much of log do you need to see

Comment: public void showdata(View view)
{
 Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from Student WHERE fname = ?", new String[]{fname}); 
 int count= c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();
    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
    tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
   TableRow tableRow;
   TextView textView,textView1,textView2,textView3,textView4,textView5;
   tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
   textView=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   textView.setText("Firstname");
   textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

Comment: textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
   tableRow.addView(textView);
    textView4=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   textView4.setText("LastName");
   textView4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
   textView4.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView4.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
   tableRow.addView(textView4);
      tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

Comment: for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++)
     {
         tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
         textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
         textView1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fname")));
         textView2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
         textView2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lname")));      
         textView1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

Comment: textView2.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);        
         tableRow.addView(textView1);
         tableRow.addView(textView2);       
         tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
         c.moveToNext() ;
     }
     setContentView(tableLayout);
db.close();
}

Comment: When it is , null the entire db displays,   When I hard code the swl to Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from emdcode WHERE code = '1A1'",null);    But the user needs o ented their codeword ( ie 1A1, 1A2, 9E6, etc )

Comment: (maybe put this into your post with a code block around it so that it formats nicely). Without the logcat with the crash it's hard to know. My initial assumption is that the string is null, or the view you are attempting to get the string from is null.

Comment: how many lines of logcat do you need to see it is over 3000 long...An thank you for your help.

Comment: You should be able to filter your logcat by only the errors (you can also set it up so you only receive logs for your app). The error will show you where your app is force closing. (You might want to edit your question and post the logcat there as the comments isn't a good place to put it). The error should only be about 30 lines long.

Comment: how would I pass the string entered in a text box to the SQL statement to search for that string.  Example user entered 1A1 the db should return that one row with the definition of 1A1.  I have done this in Java and a web based with php.  just cant figure out how with android

Comment: See edit. It's assuming a few things based of the code given.